# Sprite rotates in the destination point

Tags: c++11, sfml

I am trying to implement point-and-click control over my sprite. Everything is essentially fine, but strange artifacts occur when sprite arrives to the destination point. Looks like it constantly rotates 180 degrees over and over again. [image: Artifacts]

And normal state for comparison.
[image: Normal state]

I've tried to avoid it using this function:

```
sf::Vector2f GetDirection(const sf::Vector2f& start, const sf::Vector2f& destination) {
    sf::Vector2f dir = destination - start;
    if (GetLength(dir) <= 0.1) {
        return sf::Vector2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    return Normalize(dir);
}
```

But the condition is rarely true. Full code [is here](https://gist.github.com/montreal91/85cdcd83ba32d516bc24d6c7f4ddbabd).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have no way to "break".

You are going to 300/300. You overshoot your target. You turn. You go back. You overshoot your target. Rinse and repeat.

You are missing a check that if your current speed is more than needed to reach your target, you should just use the speed necessary. Not more.

You check is nice. But it checks if you are **less than a tenth of a pixel away** from your target. Maybe you should check less detailed. One pixel would be plenty. Replace

```
if (GetLength(dir) <= 0.1) {
```

with

```
if (GetLength(dir) <= 1.0) {
```

and it will work.